# Nib file not loaded after restart the application

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am fresher in IOS
My problem is i have 10 buttons and each button download one doc file from URL,
suppose if user click 1,5,7,8,10 number of button one by one then how can i call all 5 URL in queue and download file one by one??
help me..

Answer (score 0):

Use `NSURLSession` api and pass different URL on each button click. You have to make download task and start the task for each URL.

You can start from this turorial [here](http://www.appcoda.com/background-transfer-service-ios7/) and also look the great [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Articles/UsingNSURLSession.html)